# Delete Statement Conflicted With Same Table Reference in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an object like below:

```
public class AdminMenuItem : BaseEntity
{
    public int? ParentMenuItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public AdminMenuItem ParentMenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

I added two menuitem. One is A that has not a parent menu. The other one B and A is the parent menu item for the B.

When I delete A, it throws me the exception on below:

> ```
> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.AdminMenuItem_dbo.AdminMenuItem_ParentMenuItemId".
> ```
>
> The conflict occurred in database "A61DB", table "dbo.AdminMenuItem",
>   column 'ParentMenuItemId'.
>       The statement has been terminated

What configuration should I do to also delete child item while deleting parent ? Should I do it manually by putting it in a loop or is there a sufficient way to do it in entity framework 5 ? I try to use **WillCascadeOnDelete** but I couldnt success.

Also is there way to set child object foreign key to null ? (This is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Entity supports ON CASCADE DELETE. Please Look at this:

[cascading-deletes-with-entity-framework-related-entities-deleted-by-ef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448702/cascading-deletes-with-entity-framework-related-entities-deleted-by-ef)

and this one:

[entity-framework-on-delete-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005948/entity-framework-on-delete-cascade)

and MSDN article:

[how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx)

Comment: Not possible with self-reference though (http://stackoverflow.com/q/528529/861716)

Comment: SQL Server also only allows one cascade path, an important limitation for complex object graphs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-that-may-cause-multiple-cascade-paths