# SQL Server : table with foreign key to itself with cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a table table to hold hierarchy tree data (i.e. continents, countries, cities) like this

```
id  name    parent
-------------------
1   world   null
2   Europe  1
3   Asia    1
4   France  2
5   Paris   4
6   Lyon    4
```

I want to delete `France` and would expect the table to cascade delete all French cities. But when I create the table like this

```
create table locations 
(
    id int identity(1, 1),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    parent_id int,

    constraint pk__locations
        primary key clustered (id),

    constraint fk__locations
        foreign key (parent_id) 
            references locations (id)
                on delete cascade
                on update no action 
)
```

I got an error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk__locations' on table
>   'locations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

Info says

1. to specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION` - that is exactly what do not I want
2. to specify `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` - specified
3. modify other FOREIGN KEY constraint - I don't understand this one

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528529/self-referencing-constraint-in-ms-sql
I think you need a trigger.

Comment: you need an instead of trigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. You can solve this with an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`

```
create table locations 
(
    id int identity(1, 1),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    parent_id int,

    constraint pk__locations
        primary key clustered (id)

)
GO

INSERT INTO locations(name,parent_id)  VALUES
 ('world',null)
,('Europe',1)
,('Asia',1)
,('France',2)
,('Paris',4)
,('Lyon',4);
GO
```

--This trigger will use a recursive CTE to get all IDs following all ids you are deleting. These IDs are deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DeleteCascadeLocations ON locations
INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
    WITH recCTE AS
    (
        SELECT id,parent_id
        FROM deleted

        UNION ALL

        SELECT nxt.id,nxt.parent_id
        FROM recCTE AS prv
        INNER JOIN locations AS nxt ON nxt.parent_id=prv.id
    )
    DELETE FROM locations WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM recCTE);
END
GO
```

--Test it here, try with different IDs. You can try `WHERE id IN(4,3)` also...

```
SELECT * FROM locations;

DELETE FROM locations WHERE id=4;

SELECT * FROM locations
GO
```

--Clean-Up (Carefull with real data!)

```
if exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME='locations')
---DROP TABLE locations;
```

Comment: the `@delid` is not used anywhere ,also is it possible this will be a recursive trigger?

Comment: @Bijujose, thx, the `@delid` is a forgotten residue from tests... What would be the advantage of a recursive trigger? The recursive CTE will fetch the whole branche from a given ID down to a depth of 100 (by default). All dependant rows will be deleted in one single statement. This should be the *maximum best optimal solution ;-)*

Comment: No not the advantage , I was thinking since we are deleting from the same table weather the trigger will fire indefinetly?

Comment: @Bijujose No problem here... The `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` is a *one-time-action*, which takes place *instead of the normal deletion process*.

Comment: hey @Shnugo you hit two questions with one answer :) Sorry to all for a duplicate to this one [Self-referencing constraint in MS SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528529/self-referencing-constraint-in-ms-sql)